# How do I redirect from the root of a nested route with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Didn't find any answers online to this, basically I want the application to automatically redirect from my route root (/) to 'posts'. So `www.app.com/user/1` turns into `www.app.com/user/1/posts`

I tried using Redirect, but it actually does nothing.

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="user/:id" component={UserPage}>
            <Route path="tracks" component={UserPosts}></Route>
            <Redirect from="/" to="posts"/>
        </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Tried putting the Redirect component above, and it still does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution we are using in our project is based on `IndexRoute`:

```
<IndexRoute onEnter={redirectToMainPage} />
```

where the `redirectToMainPage` is defined as:

```
const redirectToMainPage = (nextState, replace, callback) => {    
    replace(null, '/firstPage');

    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
};
```

This will enable to select the redirect dynamically.

Also, you can use `IndexRedirect`:

```
<IndexRedirect to="/firstPage" />
```

I believe that `<Redirect>` takes an absolute path if you start with `/` in `from` and in general it is less reliable for an empty path.